# How to import modules from parent subdirs properly (Pylint E0401: Unable to import (import-error))

Tags: python, python-import, python-module, pylint

For this question I created simplified structure of my another project to recreate the problem, yet to make it simpler for you to understand.

---

#### Structure of project

```
project_directory
├─── package_one
│         module_1.py
├─── package_two
│         module_2.py
└─── main.py
```

#### Files contents

###### module_1.py

```
def dash_string(string: str) -> str:
    "Insert dashes between characters"

    return "-".join(string)
```

###### module_2.py

```
from package_one.module_1 import dash_string

def dash_string_capitals(string: str):
    "Make string capital and insert dashes between characters"

    return dash_string(string).capitalize()
```

###### main.py

```
from package_one.module_1 import dash_string
from package_two.module_2 import dash_string_capitals

EXAMPLE = "this is example string"

print(f"package_one.module_1.dash_string: {dash_string(EXAMPLE)}")
print(f"package_two.module_2.dash_string_capitals: {dash_string_capitals(EXAMPLE)}")
```

---

When I'm running `main.py` everyting is working fine without any errors. But when I'm running `module_2.py`, I'm getting error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package_one'`

So, when I'm running `pylint` on `project_directory` - everyting is fine, but when I'm running `pylint` on `package_two` - As expected, I'm getting same erorr: `E0401: Unable to import 'package_one.module_1' (import-error)`

#### So, the question is:

What is the proper way to import `dash_string` inside `module_2.py` from `module_1.py`? Is it bad project architecture and I should to reorganize it completely (Well, in my case it **should** look like that)?

Looks like I need to solve `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package_one'` error on `module_2.py` running, and pylint problem will be solved too.

I've seen solutions like adding `project_directory` to `sys.path` inside `module_2.py`, but it looks kind of ugly for me. Or is it best practise for such situations?

Comment: How do you run things? Which commands do you use? You should try `python -m package_two.module_2` instead of `python package_two/module2.py`.

Comment: Well, modifying `sys.path` is ugly but starting a program from a module in a package (which then needs to access a module in a sibling package) is ugly, too. I don't know a much cleaner way.

Comment: @sinoroc hm, yep, It actually works, thanks. But pylint throws same error. So, I think I'll just go the ugly way and modify the `sys.path` as @MichaelButscher said.
Thanks guys

Comment: I would really recommend against doing any kind of `sys.path` or `PYTHONPATH` manipulation. Why would you, if you say that it is working as expected? -- What is the issue with *pylint*? It might just be a false positive or a misunderstanding on the way to use *pylint*. Why would you put the priority on the *pylint* output rather than on the clean working code?

Comment: @sinoroc In my real projects package_one is the directory with database setup and db models, package_two is directory with tests. I use SQLAlchemy ORM, and I need to import Models from directory with database from test directory